# How to print out planes by airline

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey im using a hashmap of string and flights to create a flight store called planeStore.  So then i made another store(Airline store) also using a hashmap. I put the planeStore into the AirlineStore.  But i cant get the airlines printing out with the planes.

I thought by putting string airlineName into Airlines constrcutor. And passing in "Plane Name"  When creating Airline airline = new Airline("PlaneName"); that this would work but it hasnt.

here is my code:

**Airline**

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Airline 
{
    private String airlineName;
    private HashMap<String, PlaneStore> map;

    public Airline(String airlineName)
    {
        this.airlineName = "";
        map = new HashMap<String, PlaneStore>();
    }
    public void add(PlaneStore plane)
    {
        map.put(airlineName, plane);
    }
    public void remove(String flight)
    {
        map.remove(flight);
    }
    public void printPlane()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Flight List********");
        for (PlaneStore plane: map.values()) {
             //System.out.println(plane);
            // class
            // or:
            System.out.println(airlineName);
            System.out.println(plane.toString());

        }

    }

}
```

plane.toString is the toString of the PlaneStore:

```
public String toString() {
        return "PlaneStore [airlineName=" + airlineName + ", planeMap="
                + planeMap + "]";
    }
```

**MainApp**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MainApp 
{
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();  
    }

    public void start()
    {
        Airline airline1 = new Airline("AerLingus");
        Airline airline2 = new Airline("Ryan Air");
        PlaneStore planeStore = new PlaneStore("Aer Lingus");
        PlaneStore planeStore2 = new PlaneStore("Ryan Air");

        Flight p1 = new Flight("Aer Lingus","A01", 150.5, 10.5, 500, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);
        Flight p2 = new Flight("Aer Lingus","B01", 50.3, 1.5, 91, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.CORPORATE);
        Flight p3 = new Flight("Aer Lingus","C01", 12.2, -3.1, 56, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);


        Flight p4 = new Flight("Ryan Air","D01", 10.5, 1.5, 430, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.PRIVATE);
        Flight p5 = new Flight("Ryan Air","E01", 0.3, 2.1, 101, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.CORPORATE);
        Flight p6 = new Flight("Ryan Air","F01", 2.2, -3, 291, Flight.AIRPLANETYPE.AIRBUS);
        planeStore.add(p1);
        planeStore.add(p2);
        planeStore.add(p3);
        planeStore.print();

        airline1.add(planeStore);
        airline1.add(planeStore);
        airline1.add(planeStore);
        airline1.printPlane();

        planeStore2.add(p4);
        planeStore2.add(p5);
        planeStore2.add(p6);

        airline2.add(planeStore2);
        airline2.add(planeStore2);
        airline2.add(planeStore2);
        airline2.printPlane();



    }

}
```

Comment: is the airlineName ever assigned to anything other than ""?

Comment: It looks like you are not using your map keys. So you should use a java.util.List instead of a Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Airline` construtor receives a `String` argument but you are not assignment the instance variable `airlineName` of the class Airline to this argument. You are just making `airlineName` set to "".

```
public Airline(String airlineName)
    {
        this.airlineName = "";
        map = new HashMap<String, PlaneStore>();
    }
```

you mean:

```
public Airline(String airlineName)
        {
            this.airlineName = airlineName;
            map = new HashMap<String, PlaneStore>();
        }
```

Looking further in your code, it appears that each `Airline` class will have an `map` but you only add a key to this map, along with the values `PlaneStore`. So it appears that you will never have two or more keys for each `map` on each `Airline` class. Therefore, there is no point in using `map`, you can use instead an `ArrayList`.

If I understand correctly your objective you can simplify your AirLine class to something like this:

```
public class Airline 
{
    private String airlineName;                // Name of the company
    private ArrayList <PlaneStore> planeStore;

    public Airline(String airlineName)
    {
        this.airlineName = airlineName;
        map = new ArrayList<PlaneStore>();
    }
    public void add(PlaneStore plane){ planeStore.add(plane);}


    public void printPlane()
    {

        System.out.println(airlineName);
        System.out.println("\n********Flight List********");
        for (PlaneStore plane: planeStore)
        {
            System.out.println(plane.toString());
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're setting airlineName to "" rather than the String that you pass into it throught the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the code to read `this.airlineName = airlineName;` you should be ok with this part.

By the way it still looks like you are using the same key for every plane you add. This will constantly overwrite the last plane you added with the new one. If you want to be able to print out all of the planes, you need to give them each a unique key. Otherwise this won't work.